# Error with Node.js project startup using pm2

Tags: node.js, node-modules, pm2

I have a productive project in Node.js. To start it, I use pm2 and I have npm, pm2, and node installed. The problem is that when I start everything and give a pm2 status, it sends everything with errored. To see what happens, I gave a pm2 logs and it throws me several errors like this:

```
/root/.pm2/logs/index-out.log last 15 lines:
/root/.pm2/logs/index-error.log last 15 lines:
0|index    |     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
0|index    |     at Object.<anonymous> (/DATA/rabbitmq/util/tools.js:2:19)
0|index    |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
0|index    |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
0|index    |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
0|index    |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
0|index    |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
0|index    |     at Module.Hook._require.Module.require (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/require-in-the-middle/index.js:101:39) {
0|index    |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
0|index    |   requireStack: [
0|index    |     '/DATA/rabbitmq/util/tools.js',
0|index    |     '/DATA/rabbitmq/util/loadEnv.js',
0|index    |     '/DATA/rabbitmq/index.js'
0|index    |   ]
0|index    | }
```

Answer (score 0):

To solv this, need to run the net command

```
npm i
```